# How to display jquery modal popup on mvc 4 button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing one mvc project where I have one button. When I clicked on button one popup with textbox and button should appear. I tried as below. Instead of getting popup when the page first loads required textbox and button in page only(supposed to display when the button clicked) This is what I tried.

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
```

Style information I copied from https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form(many lines of code so I am not posting here)
This is my script and popup code.

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <form>
        <fieldset>

            <label for="name">Enter your Comments Here</label>

            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->

            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">

        </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>
<script>
    $("#Delete").button().on("click", function () {

        dialog.dialog("open");

    });


</script>
```

This is my mvc code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestRendering", FormMethod.Post))
    {
   <td scope="col"><input type="button" id="Delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons red" value="Delete" /></td>

    }
```

Am I going wrong in this process? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="button" id="Delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons red" value="Delete" />

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Enter your Comments Here</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->

      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#Delete').click(function() {
  $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function() {
      jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
        jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
      })
    }
  });
});
```

<kbd>[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/6FGqN/2750/)</kbd>

Comment: I tried same thing. Popup is not appearing. Text written inside <p> tag appears in web page only. It is supposed to appear on button click Delete.

Comment: `autoOpen: false ` use this

Comment: still I am not able to get. Textbox is appearing in webpage only. Button is not firing up. Do I need to change button type?

Comment: i changed button type from button to submit now button is firing but popup is not appearing. Where i should put autoOpen property?

Comment: Query(document).ready(function() { this set of code should i write inside script tags?

Comment: Now i put button above div tag. its working fine but my supposed to be inside mvc razor  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestRendering", FormMethod.Post))
    { }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105863/discussion-between-hazard-and-niranjan).

Comment: You can use it.If you've observed I've took your `input` between `td`